# Embedding Twitter Feed on a Website

Tags: twitter, embed

I am trying to embed the latest tweets from a Twitter account on a website - www.CochlearImplantOnline.com on the sidebar.  I am using this code:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://twitter.com/javascripts/blogger.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://api.twitter.com/1/statuses/user_timeline/cochlearimplant.json?callback=twitterCallback2&count=3"></script>
```

When I implemented this code, it doesn't show up at all.  What could I be doing wrong?

Answer (score 3):

This doesn't look like the code from the twitter widget for embedding a feed.  Are you sure you copied it from that widget?  This is what it looks like when I copy the widget embed code on my account:

```
    <a class="twitter-timeline" href="https://twitter.com/marycamacho" data-widget-id="275430111547887616">Tweets by @marycamacho</a>
<script>!function(d,s,id){var js,fjs=d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];if(!d.getElementById(id)){js=d.createElement(s);js.id=id;js.src="//platform.twitter.com/widgets.js";fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js,fjs);}}(document,"script","twitter-wjs");</script>
```

Comment: I am aware that Twitter has widgets for which we can copy and paste - https://dev.twitter.com/docs/embedded-timelines.  However, that is not what I am looking for.  I just want to display the last three tweets in simple text and be able to customize the text with CSS.  You can see examples of other Twitter "widgets" that I am trying to create - 

http://www.warchild.org.uk/ (on the bottom of the page on the left)
http://lorenzoverzini.com/ (scroll down until you see "Twitter")
http://visitbruges.be/home (See "Social Stream" on the left side as you scroll down)

Answer (score 1):

Go to [publish.twitter.com](https://publish.twitter.com) and put your twitter URL into the search box eg. https://twitter.com/Twitter
Then you get your embedded code for your twitter feed. You can also customize.